# Windows Store App URLs at ms-windows-store:// - Broken Now?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Recently the Windows Store and Windows Phone Store have merged as you might have seen on the developer portal, the user-facing Windows Store website, etc.

Since this has happened, a few links we have been using in our apps have stopped working.

Such as:

- Link to our publisher page - `ms-windows-store:search?publisher=OurPublisherName`
- Link to rate/review our app - `ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid=OurAppId`

Documentation on these are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh974767.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Anyone else having this trouble?

Comment: For my review link, I use the one with the package family name: `ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=myPackageId`. I just checked and it works for me. I'll note that I had originally tried using the same review link that you use - I never got it to work (and that was prior to the dev center changes). Not much we can do now, but MS has too many different versions of these links floating around.

Comment: Thanks, I got your suggestion to work, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve these issues with URLs of the format:

- Publisher page - `ms-windows-store:Publisher?name=OurPublisherName`
- Review page - `ms-windows-store:Review?PFN=OurPackageFamilyName`

To find these values on your account, login to the new Windows Dev Center | Select Your App | App Overview | Scroll down to App Identity.

`Package/Properties/PublisherDisplayName` will display your publisher name. Be sure to replace any spaces with `%20`. `Package Family Name (PFN)` is the PFN for this app.

Answer (score 0):

I had a broken link because I chose a [private audience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/choose-visibility-options#audience) and forgot to set that up.

I was receiving notifcation from the store message centre "Congratulations! JobTalk is now published to the Store"  When I clicked the link I got

```
We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.
The URL may be misspelled or the page you're looking for is no longer available.
```